# Bash Script + Create Symlink to Website

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file, linux-mint

I have following **batch**-script:

```
echo [InternetShortcut] > "%basepath%\files\new\link.URL"
echo URL=http://google.com >> "%basepath%\files\new\link.URL"
echo IconFile=http://google.com/favicon.ico >> "%basepath%\files\new\link.URL"
echo IconIndex=0 >> "%basepath%\files\new\link.URL"
```

In Windows 7, this creates a symlink on the desktop and when clicked it opens Google in the webbrowser.

I am trying to achieve the exact same thing with a small bash script, but this:

```
ln -s http://google.com ~/Arbeitsfläche/new
```

doesnt work, but at the same time its the only way I can think of doing it.

p.s. if it does matter: the bash script is supposed to work on Debian.

Comment: That's not a shortcut, that's a symlink

Comment: thanks for the explanation and I will correct it, however that did not really help me..

Comment: When you say **This creates a symlink on the desktop and when clicked it opens Google in the webbrowser.** which OS you refer?

Comment: @tuxuday: Windows 7, but I guess this works on every Windows version.

Comment: and by this **I am trying to achieve the exact same thing with a small bash script, but this:**  you are referring win or linux?

Comment: @tuxuday: Linux! I am simply trying to get the same functions from the script above (BATCH on WINDOWS) working in another script (BASH on LINUX). I hope I was able to explain what I mean. Or let me put it this way: I need a Bash script (for Linux) that creates a symlink to a http website!

Comment: @Andrej, what you are asking is not OS specific, but DM (Desktop Manager) specific in Linux. For example for Gnome, you can do this: http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-create-desktop-shortcuts-for-websites-in-ubuntu-11-10-tip/

Comment: Okay, I think I confused you, the Windows 7 case is a URL shortcut file, the second case currently _is_ a symlink. I'll try to find the opendesktop equivalent

Comment: By opendesktop I meant freedesktop, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a `.desktop` file (see [Desktop Entry spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html)), here's an example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
URL=http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Great! :) Finally an answer that does exactly what I have been trying for hours now! Sorry if I sounded mean before, but I dont get why people keep bothering when they clearly dont know the solution... Anyways, thanks again Hasturkun!!

Comment: @Andrej that's still not a good reason to be rude to those who are trying to help. Besides, if *"people keep bothering when they clearly dont know the solution"* that might be a down to the (lack of) clarity of your questions. Try to identify what caused the misunderstanding, and use it to improve your questions.

Comment: @ShawnChin I have not been rude to no1. I said "Thanks, but thats not what I was asking for." I did improve my question multiple times, but it seems some people have not been reading my question, but just answered for the sake of answering (points? upvotes?) and tbh thats not what SO is about in my opinion. Anyways, its fine now :) And sorry if some1 felt that I was rude.

Answer (score 0):

**ln** in linux is used to create name-aliases, kind of, in linux. Suppose you have file /somelocation/X and what the same file to be referred like /someotherlocation/Y, then one uses **ln**.

What you need is Launcher.

```
Right Click on the linux desktop, select "Create Launcher"

Use the Following Settings to make a link to google:

Type: Location
Name: Google
Location: http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Well thanks, but thats not what I was asking for. I need a script to automate this process!!

Comment: Did you tried to create a launcher and tested whether it works?

Comment: Didnt you read my reply? I dont care whether this works or not (btw. I am sure it does!), because its not what I am looking for!!

Comment: @Andrej if it works, it'll create a file that you can look at to see if you can recreate the same from a script.

Comment: @nicerobot: I asked how to create a symlink or shortcut or whatever you want to call it by using a bash script! Not more and not less. If that is impossible, than I will try to find another way, but until than, please only answer if you actually have a constructive answer!!!

Comment: @Andrej, with this kind of answers you won't get any solution.

Comment: @tuxuday Actually, I just did.

Comment: @Andrej i didn't say this was an answer to your question. I was pointing out how you can use this "answer" to solve your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Create bash script file (~/bin/urlfile):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

launcher="$(pwd)/$1.desktop";

#echo -e "#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open\n\n[Desktop Entry]\nVersion=1.0\nName=$1\nComment=Open Link (URL): $2\nComment[ru_RU]=Открыть ссылку (URL): $2\nIcon=applications-internet\nURL=$2\nType=Link" | tee "$launcher"

echo -e "#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open\n
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=$1
Comment=Open Link (URL): $2
Comment[ru_RU]=Открыть ссылку (URL): $2
Icon=applications-internet
URL=$2
Type=Link" | tee "$launcher" &&

chmod +x "$launcher"
```

& Run:

```bsh
urlfile 'Bash Script + Create Symlink to Website' 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532754/bash-script-create-symlink-to-website'
```

You'll get a file in home directory.